# How to export C++ functions with GCC?

Tags: c++, linux, export, shared

I'm using Code::Blocks to compile a shared library on Ubuntu. When I make a simple main.c file with:

```
void* CreateInterface()
{
    int* x = (int*)malloc( sizeof( int ) );
    *x = 1337;
    return x;
}
```

This works fine and I can find the function CreateInterface with dlsym in another application. However, I want the function to create an instance of a class written in C++. I tried the following:

```
#include "IRender.h"

extern "C"
{
    void* CreateInterface()
    {
        return new Flow::Render::IRender();
    }
}
```

This compiled fine, but now my other application fails to find CreateInterface. How should I deal with this?

Comment: How about trying a middle case; enclose the first CreateInterface() in an extern "C" block, and see what happens.

Comment: How is the other application "find"ing CreateInterface in the first place? Is the other application `#include` ing a header file of your own design? If so, then the `extern "C"` needs to be applied to both the header and implementation of the function.

Comment: As I said it is finding the function using dlsym and it only works if I compile the whole file as C.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem by making a .cpp file with the declaration:

```
extern "C" void* CreateInterface()
{
    return new Flow::Render::IRender();
}
```

and a .c file with the header like this:

```
extern void* CreateInterface();
```